# How to set open graph image, after load the page without og image and call the image by AJAX

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-opengraph

After load the article/page, I then make ajax call to get the article images from API, So the images of article get loaded after page load (and that's because bring them take long time), Now I want to make the returned image as og:image value.

See as an example this page for specific car:

http://arabiauto.com/Autos/Details/63577

How make the facebook share show the image of car (that come by ajax after load page)?

Any help please?

Comment: Do you have some code to show your working so far?

Comment: Facebook will not run any javascript when fetching the URL. The fetch the URL you specified so any og-tags needs to be in the HTML you return

Comment: Is there any work around!

Comment: Only one: Use an individual URL for each piece of content you want to share, and have your server respond with an HTML document that contains all the relevant OG meta data when that URL is requested by the FB scraper.

Comment: @CBroe How is that? Could you please explain more?

Comment: What is there to explain, what are you having trouble with specifically?

Comment: I can't share the image of car/Automobile because I call images by ajax after web page get loaded